# how to save video in documents foler?

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

i wrote code for dynamic video , that is to be stored in documents and use it any wher of that video in our program

```
UIImagePickerController *ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; 
ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary; 
ipc.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:ipc.sourceType];
ipc.delegate = self; 
ipc.editing = NO; 
[self presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES];
```

Answer (score -1):

The below code will help you,

```
 #pragma mark UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)imagePickerControl didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{

    NSURL *videoURL;
    NSString *type = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    if ([type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeVideo] || 
        [type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
    { 
        videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    }
    [self saveVideoToFileFromURL:videoURL];
    [self  dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

-(void)saveVideoToFileFromURL:(NSURL*)videoStorageURL
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSDate *todayDateObj = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyyHHmmss"];    
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"movie%@.mov",[dateFormat stringFromDate:todayDateObj]] ]; 
    [dateFormat release];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoStorageURL];
    [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Following code method insert into AppDelegate.h file

```
@property (nonatomic , retain) MPMoviePlayerViewController *mPlayer;
-(void)initAndPlayMovie:(NSURL *)movieURL andViewController:(UIViewController*)vCtr;
```

Following code insert into AppDelegate .m file

## pragma mark - Media player

```
-(void)initAndPlayMovie:(NSURL *)movieURL andViewController:(UIViewController*)vCtr
{
    self.mPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    // set source type streaming
    [self.mPlayer.moviePlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown];
 
    [self.mPlayer.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
 
    // fit to screen mode
    [self.mPlayer.moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit];
 
    // full screen mode
    [self.mPlayer.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
 
    [vCtr presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.mPlayer];
}
 
-(void)stopPlaying_dismissMoviePlayer
{
    [self.mPlayer.moviePlayer stop];
    [self.mPlayer dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
}
 
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [self stopPlaying_dismissMoviePlayer];
}
```

Following code insert into .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
#import "ASIDownloadCache.h"
 
@interface locallyCacheMP3FileViewController : UIViewController
 
- (IBAction)playAudio:(UIButton*)sender;
 
@property (nonatomic, retain) ASIHTTPRequest *rqstForAudio;
 
@end
```

Synthesize the variable

```
@synthesize rqstForAudio=_rqstForAudio;
```

Create method name as playAudio which connect to the button press event.

```
#pragma mark - View lifecycle
 
- (IBAction)playAudio:(UIButton*)sender
{
 
    NSString *strAudioURL=@"Your Video link";
 
    // check first locally exists or not
    NSString *strPathToAudioCache=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                                   [(NSArray*)NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0],
                                   AudioFolder];
 
    NSDictionary *dOfAudios=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:strPathToAudioCache];
 
    if([dOfAudios valueForKey:strAudioURL]) {
        [APP_DEL initAndPlayMovie:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[dOfAudios valueForKey:strAudioURL]] andViewController:self];
    } else {
        NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strAudioURL];
        NSString *strPathToDownload=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[(NSArray*)NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0],
                                     [strAudioURL lastPathComponent]];
 
        if(!self.rqstForAudio || [self.rqstForAudio isFinished]) {
            self.rqstForAudio=[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:audioURL];
            [self.rqstForAudio setDelegate:self];
            [self.rqstForAudio setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES];
            [self.rqstForAudio setCachePolicy:ASIUseDefaultCachePolicy];
            [self.rqstForAudio setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];
            [self.rqstForAudio setDidFailSelector:@selector(failedToLoad:)];
            [self.rqstForAudio setDidFinishSelector:@selector(finishedLoading:)];
            [self.rqstForAudio setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
            [self.rqstForAudio setDownloadDestinationPath:strPathToDownload];
            [self.rqstForAudio startAsynchronous];
        }
 
    }
}
```

[You can download the Source code and tutorial here](http://sugartin.info/2011/10/03/locally-cache-mp3-file-with-use-of-asihttp-request/)